# Failed to load resource 406 (Not Acceptable)

Tags: php

I saw this error today, yesterday everything was good.
Issue based on hosting or i don't know when i run the files on the localhost everythings fine and working correctly. Maybe there is problem with hosting secure ?
If anyone has any tips I would be very grateful.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)

```
<?php
if( isset($_SESSION["DATAGLOBAL"][0]) && !empty($_SESSION["DATAGLOBAL"][0]) )
    $C->LANGUAGE = $_SESSION["DATAGLOBAL"][0];
$this->load_langfile('inside/dashboard.php');
$this->load_langfile('global/global.php');
if( $this->user->is_logged )
{
    $D->is_logged  = 1;
    $errored       = 0;
    $txterror      = '';
    $action        = 0;
    $wsee          = -1;
    $txtstatus     = $txtvalueatach = $txttypeattach = $id_wall       = '';
    $typeattach    = $posted_in     = 0;
    if( isset($_POST["wseep"]) && $_POST["wseep"] != -1 )
    {
        $wsee = $this->db1->e($_POST["wseep"]);
    }
    if( $wsee == -1 )
    {
        $errored  = 1;
        $txterror = $this->lang('global_post_txterror6');
    }
    if( $errored == 0 )
    {
        if( isset($_POST["pin"]) && $_POST["pin"] != '' )
        {
            $posted_in = $this->db1->e($_POST["pin"]);
        }
        if( isset($_POST["idw"]) && $_POST["idw"] != '' )
        {
            $id_wall = $this->db1->e($_POST["idw"]);
        }
        if( isset($_POST["newstatus"]) && $_POST["newstatus"] != '' )
        {
            $txtstatus = $this->db1->e(htmlspecialchars($_POST["newstatus"]));
        }
        if( isset($_POST["typeattach"]) && $_POST["typeattach"] != 0 )
        {
            $typeattach = $this->db1->e($_POST["typeattach"]);
        }
        if( isset($_POST["atach-value"]) && $_POST["atach-value"] != '' )
        {
            $txtvalueatach = $this->db1->e($_POST["atach-value"]);
        }
        $withattach  = 0;
        $endtxtatach = '';
        $codep       = uniqueCode(11, 1, 'posts', 'code');
        if( $typeattach == 1 || $typeattach == 2 || $typeattach == 3 || $typeattach == 4 || $typeattach == 5 || $typeattach == 6 || $typeattach == 7 || $typeattach == 8 || $typeattach == 9 )
        {
            switch( $typeattach )
            {
                case 1:
                    $images_post = $_FILES['images_post'];
                    $numphotos   = count($images_post['name']);
                    if( $images_post['name'][0] )
                    {
                        if( $numphotos > $C->NUM_PHOTOS_POST )
                        {
                            $errored  = 1;
                            $txterror = $this->lang('global_post_txterror1') . ' ' . $C->NUM_PHOTOS_POST;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $photos     = array();
                            $tmp_photos = array();
                            for( $i = 0; $i < $numphotos; $i++ )
                            {
                                if( $images_post['size'][$i] > $C->SIZE_PHOTO || $images_post['size'][$i] == 0 )
                                {
                                    $errored  = 1;
                                    $txterror = $this->lang('global_post_txterror2') . ': ' . $images_post['name'][$i];
                                    break;
                                }
                                $loadedtype = $images_post['type'][$i];
                                if( $loadedtype == "image/jpeg" || $loadedtype == "image/gif" || $loadedtype == "image/png" || $loadedtype == "video/m4v" )
                                {
                                    switch( $loadedtype )
                                    {
                                        case "image/jpeg":
                                            $uploadfile .= '.jpg';
                                            $mfilename  .= '.jpg';
                                            break;
                                        case "image/gif":
                                            $uploadfile .= '.gif';
                                            $mfilename  .= '.gif';
                                            break;
                                        case "video/m4v":
                                            $uploadfile .= '.gif';
                                            $mfilename  .= '.gif';
                                            break;
                                        case "image/png":
                                            $uploadfile .= '.png';
                                            $mfilename  .= '.png';
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $errored  = 1;
                                    $txterror = $this->lang('global_post_txterror3') . ': ' . $images_post['name'][$i];
                                    break;
                                }
                                $tmp_photos[] = $images_post['tmp_name'][$i];
                                $photos[]     = $codep . '-' . $i . $extens;
                            }
                            if( $errored == 0 )
                            {
                                foreach( $photos as $key => $fname )
                                {
                                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_photos[$key], '../' . $C->FOLDER_PHOTOS . $fname);
                                    $thumbnail = new SmartImage('../' . $C->FOLDER_PHOTOS . $fname, true);
                                    $thumbnail->mycrop($C->widthPhotoThumbail, $C->widthPhotoThumbail, 'center');
                                    $thumbnail->saveImage('../' . $C->FOLDER_PHOTOS . 'min1/' . $fname);
                                    $thumbnail->close();
                                }
                                unset($mythumb);
                                $txttypeattach = 'photo';
                            }
                            $endtxtatach = implode(',', $photos);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if( !empty($txtvalueatach) )
                    {
                        if( substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 20) == "https://youtube.com/" || substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 24) == "https://www.youtube.com/" || substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 16) == "www.youtube.com/" || substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 12) == "youtube.com/" || substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 19) == "http://youtube.com/" || substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 23) == "http://www.youtube.com/" || substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 16) == "http://youtu.be/" )
                        {
                            parse_str(parse_url($txtvalueatach, PHP_URL_QUERY), $my_array_of_vars);
                            if( substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 16) == 'http://youtu.be/' )
                            {
                                $endtxtatach = str_replace('http://youtu.be/', 'yt:', $txtvalueatach);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $endtxtatach = 'yt:' . $my_array_of_vars['v'];
                            }
                        }
                        elseif( substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 17) == "http://vimeo.com/" || substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 21) == "http://www.vimeo.com/" || substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 18) == "https://vimeo.com/" || substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 22) == "https://www.vimeo.com/" || substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 14) == "www.vimeo.com/" || substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 10) == "vimeo.com/" )
                        {
                            $endtxtatach = 'vm:' . (int) substr(parse_url($txtvalueatach, PHP_URL_PATH), 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $errored  = 1;
                            $txterror = $this->lang('global_post_txterror4');
                        }
                        if( !empty($endtxtatach) )
                        {
                            $withattach    = 1;
                            $typeattach    = 2;
                            $txttypeattach = 'video';
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if( !empty($txtvalueatach) )
                    {
                        if( substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 23) == "https://soundcloud.com/" || substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 27) == "https://www.soundcloud.com/" || substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 22) == "http://soundcloud.com/" || substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 22) == "https://m.soundcloud.com/" || substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 22) == "http://soundcloud.com/" || substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 22) == "http://www.soundcloud.com/" || substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 15) == "soundcloud.com/" || substr($txtvalueatach, 0, 19) == "www.soundcloud.com/" )
                        {
                            $endtxtatach = 'sc:' . parse_url($txtvalueatach, PHP_URL_PATH);
                        }
                        else
                            $endtxtatach = $this->db1->e(htmlspecialchars(trim(clearnl($txtvalueatach))));
                        if( !empty($endtxtatach) )
                        {
                            $withattach    = 1;
                            $typeattach    = 3;
                            $txttypeattach = 'music';
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if( !empty($txtvalueatach) )
                    {
                        $endtxtatach = $this->db1->e(htmlspecialchars(trim(clearnl($txtvalueatach))));
                        if( !empty($endtxtatach) )
                        {
                            $withattach    = 1;
                            $typeattach    = 4;
                            $txttypeattach = 'map';
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 5:
                    if( !empty($txtvalueatach) )
                    {
                        $endtxtatach = $this->db1->e(htmlspecialchars(trim(clearnl($txtvalueatach))));
                        if( !empty($endtxtatach) )
                        {
                            $withattach    = 1;
                            $typeattach    = 5;
                            $txttypeattach = 'visited';
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 6:
                    if( !empty($txtvalueatach) )
                    {
                        $endtxtatach = $this->db1->e(htmlspecialchars(trim(clearnl($txtvalueatach))));
                        if( !empty($endtxtatach) )
                        {
                            $withattach    = 1;
                            $typeattach    = 6;
                            $txttypeattach = 'food';
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 7:
                    if( !empty($txtvalueatach) )
                    {
                        $endtxtatach = $this->db1->e(htmlspecialchars(trim(clearnl($txtvalueatach))));
                        if( !empty($endtxtatach) )
                        {
                            $withattach    = 1;
                            $typeattach    = 7;
                            $txttypeattach = 'movie';
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 8:
                    if( !empty($txtvalueatach) )
                    {
                        $endtxtatach = $this->db1->e(htmlspecialchars(trim(clearnl($txtvalueatach))));
                        if( !empty($endtxtatach) )
                        {
                            $withattach    = 1;
                            $typeattach    = 8;
                            $txttypeattach = 'book';
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 9:
                    if( !empty($txtvalueatach) )
                    {
                        $endtxtatach = $this->db1->e(htmlspecialchars(trim(clearnl($txtvalueatach))));
                        if( !empty($endtxtatach) )
                        {
                            $withattach    = 1;
                            $typeattach    = 9;
                            $txttypeattach = 'game';
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    if( $errored == 0 )
    {
        if( empty($txtstatus) && empty($endtxtatach) )
        {
            $errored  = 1;
            $txterror = $this->lang('global_post_txterror5');
        }
        else
        {
            $idwall = $this->network->idwall($id_wall, $posted_in);
            $r      = $this->db1->query("INSERT INTO posts SET code='" . $codep . "', iduser=" . $this->user->id . ", post='" . $txtstatus . "', typepost='" . $txttypeattach . "', posted_in=" . $posted_in . ", id_wall=" . $idwall . ",valueattach='" . $endtxtatach . "', who_see=" . $wsee . ", whendate='" . time() . "'");
            $idpost = $this->db1->insert_id();
            $this->db1->query('INSERT INTO activities SET iduser=' . $this->user->id . ', action=3, iditem=' . $idpost . ', typeitem=1, date="' . time() . '"');
            if( $idwall != $this->user->id )
            {
                $this->db1->query("UPDATE users SET num_posts=num_posts+1 WHERE iduser=" . $this->user->id . " LIMIT 1");
                $this->db1->query("UPDATE users SET num_posts_inwall=num_posts_inwall+1 WHERE iduser=" . $idwall . " LIMIT 1");
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db1->query("UPDATE users SET num_posts=num_posts+1, num_posts_inwall=num_posts_inwall+1 WHERE iduser=" . $this->user->id . " LIMIT 1");
            }
            preg_match_all('~([#])([^\s#]+)~', str_replace(array( '\r', '\n' ), ' ', $txtstatus), $matchedHashtags);
            if( !empty($matchedHashtags[0]) )
            {
                foreach( $matchedHashtags[0] as $match )
                {
                    $hashtag = str_replace('#', '', $match);
                    $hashtag = $this->db1->e(($hashtag));
                    $this->db1->query("INSERT INTO trends SET iduser=" . $this->user->id . ", trend='" . $hashtag . "', idpost=" . $idpost . ", whendate='" . time() . "'");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if( $errored == 1 )
    {
        $message = '0: ' . $txterror;
    }
    else
    {
        $onepost        = $this->db2->fetch('
                SELECT DISTINCT idpost, posts.code as pcode, whendate, posted_in, id_wall, typepost, valueattach, numlikes, numcomments, post, who_see, username, firstname, lastname, avatar, users.iduser as uiduser, users.code as ucode, verified 
                FROM posts, users 
                WHERE 
                (users.iduser=posts.iduser) 
                AND idpost=' . $idpost . ' 
                LIMIT 1');
        $D->isaPage     = $D->isOnlyOne   = $D->isaGroup    = $D->isWithOther = 0;
        if( $onepost->posted_in == 0 )
        {
            if( $onepost->uiduser == $onepost->id_wall )
            {
                $D->isOnlyOne  = 1;
                $D->codeUser   = $onepost->ucode;
                $D->userName   = $onepost->username;
                $D->nameUser   = (empty($onepost->firstname) || empty($onepost->lastname)) ? $onepost->username : ($onepost->firstname . ' ' . $onepost->lastname);
                $D->userAvatar = $onepost->avatar;
            }
            if( $onepost->uiduser != $onepost->id_wall )
            {
                $D->isWithOther    = 1;
                $D->codeUser       = $onepost->ucode;
                $D->userName       = $onepost->username;
                $D->nameUser       = (empty($onepost->firstname) || empty($onepost->lastname)) ? $onepost->username : ($onepost->firstname . ' ' . $onepost->lastname);
                $D->userAvatar     = $onepost->avatar;
                $wallsec           = $this->network->infoBasicWall($onepost->posted_in, $onepost->id_wall);
                $D->other_code     = $wallsec->code;
                $D->other_userName = $wallsec->username;
                $D->other_nameUser = (empty($wallsec->firstname) || empty($wallsec->lastname)) ? $wallsec->username : ($wallsec->firstname . ' ' . $wallsec->lastname);
            }
        }
        if( $onepost->posted_in == 1 )
        {
            $D->isaPage   = 1;
            $D->idPage    = $onepost->id_wall;
            $thePage      = $this->db2->fetch('SELECT code, url, avatar_page, title FROM pages WHERE idpage=' . $D->idPage . ' LIMIT 1');
            $D->pUserName = $thePage->url;
            $D->pCode     = $thePage->code;
            $D->pAvatar   = $thePage->avatar_page;
            $D->pTitle    = stripslashes($thePage->title);
        }
        if( $onepost->posted_in == 2 )
        {
            $D->isaGroup = 1;
        }
        $D->a_date      = $onepost->whendate;
        $D->codeUser    = $onepost->ucode;
        $D->valueattach = $onepost->valueattach;
        $D->typepost    = $onepost->typepost;
        $D->idpost      = $onepost->idpost;

        $D->codepost         = $onepost->pcode;
        $D->idUser           = $onepost->uiduser;
        $D->numlikes         = $onepost->numlikes;
        $D->numcommentstotal = $onepost->numcomments;
        $D->post             = stripslashes($onepost->post);
        $D->whosee           = $onepost->who_see;
        $D->post             = str_replace('&lt;script&gt;', '< script >', $D->post);
        $D->post             = str_replace('&lt;/script&gt;', '< \/script >', $D->post);

        $txtpostreturn = '';
        $txtpostreturn = $this->load_template('__one-post.php', FALSE);
        unset($onePost);
        $txtpostreturn = str_replace('<script>', '&lt;script&gt;', $txtpostreturn);
        $txtpostreturn = str_replace('</script>', '&lt;/script&gt;', $txtpostreturn);
        $message       = '1: ' . $txtpostreturn;
    }
}
?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.top.window.endPostear( '<?php echo $this->db1->e($message); ?>' );
</script>
```

Comment: This is really a lot of code to read. If you can produce something shorter you will probably get more and better feedback.

Comment: formatting code

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

The HTTP 406 Not Acceptable client error response code indicates that a response matching the list of acceptable values defined in `Accept-Charset` and `Accept-Language` cannot be served.

Looks like you are using some language files, so maybe that's your issue. What do the server logs say?

Comment: POST  406 (Not Acceptable) (anonymous) @ dashboard:465 dispatch @ jquery.min.js:5 y.handle @ jquery.min.js:5 respond from Server.

Comment: How are the files being POSTed? I'm guessing that the content-type of the upoaded file is incorrectly set.